# Eclipse is showing errors even though there isn't one

Tags: java, eclipse

so I loaded up Eclipse today to start another project after a few months and for some reason, Eclipse doesn't like anything I'm doing.

As an example of what it's doing, I get two errors on the second line:

```
public ArrayList<String> markers = new ArrayList<String>();
markers.add("Maps:");
```

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
    - Syntax error on token ""Maps:"", delete 
     this token

Here is the rest of the code for this class:

```
package exercise;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Map {

    public ArrayList<String> from;
    public ArrayList<String> to;


    public ArrayList<String> markers = new ArrayList<String>();
    markers.add("Maps:");

    File file = new File("input.txt");
    private int counter = 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need a `main` method. You need to put all that code in `main()`

Comment: `markers.add("Maps:");` needs to be part of a method or intialization block.

Comment: Eclipse is doing a bad job of telling you that you aren't writing correct Java.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out for me!

Comment: Nothing to blame in Eclipse at all. The error reported be Eclipse IDE (misplaced construct) is totalle relevant according to Java grammar as explained in other comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need code to be in a method, and to run your program you need a main method. You have neither - you just open a class and start writing code. That is not possible in Java.

Something like:

```
public class Map {

    public ArrayList<String> from;
    public ArrayList<String> to;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> markers = new ArrayList<String>();
        markers.add("Maps:");
```

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to other languages, the Java requires your statements to be in some form of "block". Typically, that would be methods.

But just for the record, you could also put your stuff into [initialisier blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Given your case of course, you just create a static void main method to wrap around your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Ther reason is quite simple:

this statment has no valid scope making it invelid:

```
 markers.add("Maps:");
```

move it inside a method (e.g the main method) and everything will work fine!